# Is Hebrews 1:3 an allusion to Wisdom of Solomon 7:25-26?

Tags: hebrews, intertextuality, wisdom-of-solomon

> NET Bible Hebrews 1:3 The Son is **the radiance [ie: reflection] of
>   his glory** and **the representation of his essence**, and **he sustains
>   all things by his [ie: God's] powerful word**, and so when he had accomplished
>   cleansing for sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on
>   high.

Compare:

> Wisdom of Solomon 7: 25 For **she is the breath of the power of God**,
>   and **a pure influence flowing from the glory of the Almighty**:
>   therefore can no defiled thing fall into her. 26 For **she is the
>   brightness of the everlasting light, the unspotted mirror of the power
>   of God**, and **the image of his goodness**.
>
> The Cambridge Paragraph Bible: of the Authorized English Version.
>   (1873). (Wis 7:24–26). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

"she is the breath of the power of God" -> "he sustains all things by his [God's] powerful word"

"she is the brightness of the everlasting light, the unspotted mirror of the power of God" -> "the radiance [ie: reflection] of his glory"

"a pure influence flowing from the glory of the Almighty" -> "the representation of his essence"

Comment: You have marked "he sustains all things by his powerful word" in bold, but I can't see what in Wis 7:24-26 that could be an allusion to. Please [edit] this to explain

Comment: @curiousdannii  "she is the breath of the power of God"

Comment: @curiousdannii  Did you down-vote this question? If so, may I ask why? Perhaps I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of corresponding thought (or subject matter) might compel us to conclude so. Given more weight by the fact that both passages also both use a word only used in these two places in the entire Greek Bible,almost eliminating 'coincidence' explanations.

Firstly, the Greek of both, followed by a more conservative, literal translation of my own:

> **Wisdom 7:25-26**
>
> 25 ἀτμὶς γάρ ἐστιν τῆς τοῦ θεοῦ **δυνάμεως** καὶ *ἀπόρροια τῆς τοῦ παντοκράτορος δόξης εἰλικρινής* διὰ τοῦτο οὐδὲν μεμιαμμένον εἰς αὐτὴν παρεμπίπτει 26 **ἀπαύγασμα***  γάρ ἐστιν *φωτὸς ἀϊδίου* καὶ ἔσοπτρον ἀκηλίδωτον τῆς τοῦ θεοῦ ἐνεργείας καὶ ***εἰκὼν τῆς ἀγαθότητος αὐτοῦ***
>
> 25 For She is a breath of the **power** of God, and *an emanation of the pure glory of the Almighty*, on account of which no polluted thing can enter into her: 26 for [she] ["wisdom"—v. 24] is **the effulgence** *of the eternal light*; and a spotless mirror of the power of God and ***image of His goodness***.

<sup>* ἀπαύγασμα—"effulgence; refulgence; brightness; the shining-forth; brilliant radiance" etc. Only used here and *Heb 1:3*.</sup>

---

> **Hebrews 1:3**
>
> ὃς ὢν **ἀπαύγασμα** *τῆς δόξης* καὶ ***χαρακτὴρ τῆς ὑποστάσεως αὐτοῦ***, φέρων τε τὰ πάντα τῷ ῥήματι τῆς **δυνάμεως** ‹δι’› αὐτοῦ, καθαρισμὸν τῶν ἁμαρτιῶν ποιησάμενος ἐκάθισεν ἐν δεξιᾷ τῆς Μεγαλωσύνης ἐν ὑψηλοῖς,
>
> Who, being **the effulgence** *of His glory* and ***the very image* of His substance***; upholding all things by the word of His **power**; having made purification of [all] sin, sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>* "the very image"—translates χαρακτὴρ. (Perhaps 'exact expression' would be preferable to distinguish the words in the target language). Synonymous with εἰκὼν in most instances (cf. *Mk 12:16; Lk 20:24*; see also [Liddel & Scott](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=xarakth/r)). Hence the choice of translation. cf. *Col 1:15; Sir 24:5 Vul*.</sup>

<sup>1 *Wis 9:4; cf. Jn 16:28*.</sup>

This isn't the only case in which St. Paul is thought to have alluded to this Book (e.g. *Wis 2:24; Rom 5:12; Wis 15:7; Rom 9:21; Wis 13:1-10,14:22-31; Rom 1:18-31* etc).